# Unable to update a document's property value which is in an array of objects in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I am working on this app where I need to update a document. The document consists an array of objects among other things. So I need to update a property value in one of those objects but before updating I need to find the correct object based on array index.

```
async function updatePost (post) {

    const pendingPostIndex = post.postContent.findIndex( item => {
          return item.status === "pending";
    });

    const update = {
          pid: 0,
          postContent[pendingPostIndex].status: "completed"
    }

    await Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: post._id }, update);
}
```

The function above is called when I have to update a specific post. The parameter `post` is the document I will have to update.

Then I'm looking for the `index` of the post which is pending so that I can use the index to update the pending status to `complete` as well as the `pid` value to 0. Obviously, updating the `pid` value like this works. But not the second one.

The above code shows error in VS Code by underlining it red below the second property in the `update` object above.

The terminal says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['`

The data looks like this:

```
{
     "pid" : 4927fn380m38jc5, 
     "postContent" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "pending",
            "text" : "post 1",
            "image" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "complete",
            "text" : "post 2",
            "image" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "pending",
            "text" : "post 3",
            "image" : ""
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly following syntax is totally wrong inside object:

```
postContent[pendingPostIndex].status: "completed"
```

Secondly if you just want to update pid and status why not:

```
const update = {
          pid: 0,
          status: "completed"
}
await Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: post._id }, update);
```

EDIT based on comment:

If just want to update subdocument inside array at specific index where status is pending.
You just want:

```
const statusKeyUpdate = "postContent."+ pendingPostIndex +".status";

Post.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: post._id, "postContent.status": "pending" },
   { $set: { "pid":0, [statusKeyUpdate]:"completed" } }
)
```

Comment: I want to update a specific object inside that array subdocument by finding it with index (if possible). In my data there's no document called ```status``` as you mentioned.

Comment: 2 things: Firstly, wouldn't that update all the statuses with pending value? Secondly, ```pid``` is not inside postContent array subdocument. It's separate. Thanks for your time btw.

Comment: If you want to update element at index that you found you could use inside $set `"postContent."+ pendingPostIndex+".status"` . If pid is separate `$set: {'pid':0, "postContent."+pendingPostIndex+".status":"completed"}`